# In JavaScript, how do I split between each set of characters in a String?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

**QUESTION**

In JavaScript, what sort of Regex pattern or method can I use the `String.prototype.split()` on a String to repeatedly split between specific characters?

**EXAMPLE**

if I had the String below,

```
'a="https://google.com/" b="Johnny Bravo" c="1" d="2" charset="z"'
```

... and I want to split between each space and double quote, then store them into an array, it would appear like below

```
['a="https://google.com/"', 'b="Johnny Bravo"', 'c="1"', 'd="2"', 'charset="z"']
```

**ATTEMPT**

I had a complicated idea below. I have to search for each term and add them to an array. But, it only works if I know the key values ahead of time.

```
// if I do findAttribute(ABOVE_STRING, 'a'),
// I'll get 'a="https://google.com/"'
// then I can add it to an array

findAttribute(content, target) {
   if(!content || content === '') return {};
   let ind_val = content.indexOf("\"", ind_attr+`${target}+"=\""`.length);
   return content.slice(ind_attr,ind_val+1);
}
```

If I try splitting on each space using below

```
STRING.split(/\s+/g)
```

It will split on the wrong parts of the String

```
['a="https://google.com/"', 'b="Johnny', 'Bravo', 'c="1"', 'd="2"', 'charset="z"']
```

Comment: `STRING.match(/\w+="[^"]*"/g)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/XdWAln/1)).

Comment: [Design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern) have *nothing* in common with regular expression patterns other than the name.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you, I tried splitting with your RegExp. But, I ended up getting an array with Strings but no values. Have I implemented it correctly?

`string.split(/\w+="[^"]*"/g)`

`["", " ", " ", " ", " ", ""]`

Comment: @RedChallenger I just tried attempting it and it's successful. Except one part, I'm fixing it.

Comment: I used `.match`. **Why** did you use `.split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach:

```js
const stringToProcess = '\'a="https://google.com/" b="Johnny Bravo" c="1" d="2" charset="z"\'';

const pair = /(\w+)="([^"]*)"/g;

const attributes = {};
while (true) {
  const match = pair.exec(stringToProcess);
  if (!match) break;
  
  const [, key, value] = match;
  attributes[key] = value;
}

console.log(attributes);

/*
{
  "a": "https://google.com/",
  "b": "Johnny Bravo",
  "c": "1",
  "d": "2",
  "charset": "z"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set structure, then this kind of thing works better if you positively match to the structure of the items.  So you can do something like...

```
'a="https://google.com/" b="Johnny Bravo" c="1" d="2" charset="z"'.match(/\w+=".*?"/gm)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an object. You need to split the initial string into arrays and then make it into an object from the arrays. I'd do this way:

```js
const str = 'a="https://google.com/" b="Johnny Bravo" c="1" d="2" charset="z"';
// Split using RegEx
const arr = str.match(/\w+=(?:"[^"]*"|\d*|true|false)/g);
// Create a new object.
const obj = {};
// Loop through the array.
arr.forEach(it => {
  // Split on equals and get both the property and value.
  it = it.split("=");
  // Parse it because it may be a valid JSON, like a number or string for now.
  // Also, I used JSON.parse() because it's safer than exec().
  obj[it[0]] = JSON.parse(it[1]);
});
// Obj is done.
console.log(obj);
```

The above gives me:

```json
{
  "a": "https://google.com/",
  "b": "Johnny Bravo",
  "c": "1",
  "d": "2",
  "charset": "z"
}
```

You can use something like `obj.charset` and that gives you `z` or `obj.b` giving you `Johnny Bravo`. For the RegEx, here's the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XdWAln/2).

Comment: If you assume the part after `=` is a JSON, you can't use `"[^"]*"`, there might be escaped quotes inside.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you send me an example, please? Happy to fix it and update my answer. We're here to try help each other, let's not make it a competition please?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated the answer. I found a flaw actually.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I still don't understand what you meant. Mind clarifying?

Comment: In plain terms: I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64883737/in-javascript-how-do-i-split-between-each-set-of-characters-in-a-string/64883812?noredirect=1#comment114715089_64883737) the pattern you posted later. However, you assume that after `=`, there is a JSON object. That invalidates my pattern you used in the answer, you must fix the pattern so that it could match JSONs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ahhhhhh!!! Got it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the answer, thanks for letting me know. Can you please check.

Comment: Thank you, it definitely solves my example above. I'll mark it as the Accepted Answer.

Trying to implement it with the work issue I'm having. Getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` at exactly this part of the code `obj[it[0]] = JSON.parse(it[1]);`. Will update here or create a new issue if necessary.

Comment: @RedChallenger Sure, thanks. Also send the input so that I can see if I can make it work.

Comment: @RedChallenger Also, I used `JSON.parse()` because it's safer than `exec()`.

Comment: It is still not match full substrings between quotes with escaped quotes. @RedChallenger You should edit the current question to clarify the format of the incoming strings. Do not re-post the same issues.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman if one of those values in the string looked like below, how would you revise your answer?

`a="https://google.com/abc?format=jpeg" b="shoo?format=jpeg" c="Daxter Lab"`

This above string triggers the error below
`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input `


It seems to split by any `=` instead of those outside the double quotes.

Comment: @RedChallenger Ah, I missed it. Okay, anyway you have got your answer. Enjoy.